# Regular Expression Problem - Matching A Single Letter. Exclude consecutive letters

Tags: regex

I'm having an issue creating a regular expression that will give me what I want. I need your help! So the text we are using is:

```
S      1SS          1S
```

"S" and "1S" are matches. "1SS" is not a match. I would like it to be a little more specific than just excluding anything with three characters but that may be a solution.

Any other ideas on how to exclude "1SS"? I can't figure it out!

Thank you,

Mark S.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative lookahead pattern to avoid matching a consecutive letter `S`:

```
\b\d*S(?!S)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/sv467b/2

Explanations: `\b` matches a word boundary to ensure that this won't match the second `S` in two consecutive `S`es. `\d*` matches zero or more digits to allow optional preceding numbers. `S` is followed by `(?!S)`, a negative lookahead pattern to ensure that what follows `S` is not another `S`.

Comment: Is there any way you can give a break down of what this Regex is doing?

Comment: Glad to be of help. I've updated my answer with explanations. Also, since you now mention that you're only trying to match the letter `S`, there's no more need for a capture group and a backreference, and I've updated the regex accordingly. Please mark this answer as accepted if you do find it to be correct. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect, yes this is it. I was going to say that the number could be something other than "1" but you addressed this in your updated answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A regexp with more general applications is something like:

```
\b(?:(.)(?!\1))+\b
```

- \b is for word boundaries.
- List item
- (?:) is a non-capturing group.
- (?:) is a negative lookahead group.
- \1 is the group reference.